# Is the US Southern Land Border still closed for "non-essential" travel?

Tags: usa, borders, mexico

I live near Tijuana, Mexico.  I have a B1/B2 visitor visa for the United States, meaning that since March I have not been allowed to cross the southern border into the US as the land-borders have been closed for non-essential travel (see [here](https://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/border-baja-california/story/2020-03-20/u-s-mexico-border-partial-shutdown)).  This closure was extended in June for another month (see [here](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/06/16/us-mexico-border-closure-extended-323216)) and then in July was extended for at least another month (see [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/14/politics/us-canada-border-closure-extension/index.html)) until 21st August 2020.

It is now almost 21st August, however I haven't been able to find anything that says whether the border will be reopened for non-essential travel from that date.

Is the southern land-border still closed, and is there a date yet for reopening?

Comment: Note that this only applies to the land border. You can still enter the US by air for non-essential travel.

Comment: @JonathanReez yes that is was user102008 commented.  But for me to drive to San Diego costs me a few dollars of gas and maybe 30-45 minute drive from my house.  For me to fly would be $300+ for airfares, and then several hours of flights (you can't fly from TIJ to any destination in the US without flying elsewhere in Mexico first).  Doesn't really make it worth it to go to the supermarket to buy things I can't get here  The border restrictions are frustrating considering there are still thousands crossing every day, but I can wait

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The land borders are currently restricted for entry from Mexico into the US until 8 November, 2021.

(travel INTO Mexico continues unrestricted as normal)

From 8 November, 2021, fully vaccinated travelers may enter the US via the land borders for non-essential travel.

From January 2022, both essential and non-essential travelers must be fully vaccinated to enter the US via the land borders.

Source - there were a series of Tweets by the Department of Homeland Security on 20 October, 2021:

[Tweet 1](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800105259479042):

> As previously announced, starting Nov 8, travelers from Mexico and
> Canada who are fully vaccinated for #COVID19 may enter the U.S. for
> non-essential travel via land and ferry ports of entry.

[Tweet 2](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800106656174082):

> The timing of this change is aligned with the new international air
> travel system that will also be implemented in November.

[Tweet 3](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800107566374915):

> Restrictions continue to apply to non-essential travelers who are not
> fully vaccinated.

[Tweet 4](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800108614868995):

> Beginning in January 2022, both essential and non-essential travelers
> from Canada and Mexico must be fully vaccinated for #COVID19 and
> provide related proof of vaccination to enter the U.S. via land or
> ferry ports of entry.

---

Shortly after asking this question I found the answer in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/DHS_Wolf/status/1294272922559930370) by Chad Wolf, the acting secretary of Homeland Security:

> We continue to work with our Canadian and Mexican partners to slow the
> spread of #COVID19. Accordingly, we have agreed to extend the
> limitation of non-essential travel at our shared land ports of entry
> through September 21.

I also found this [Fact Sheet](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2020/08/14/fact-sheet-dhs-measures-border-limit-further-spread-coronavirus) on the DHS website that also links to the same tweet, so it looks like this tweet is the official announcement.

So for now the borders are still restricted until at least Sept 21. The list of exceptions for the border closure is as follows:

- U.S. citizens and lawful permanent residents returning to the United States;
- Individuals traveling for medical purposes (e.g., to receive medical treatment in the United States);
- Individuals traveling to attend educational institutions;
- Individuals traveling to work in the United States (e.g., individuals working in the farming or agriculture industry who must travel between the United States and Mexico in furtherance of such work);
- Individuals traveling for emergency response and public health purposes (e.g., government officials or emergency responders entering the United States to support federal, state, local, tribal, or territorial government efforts to respond to COVID-19 or other emergencies);
  Individuals engaged in lawful cross-border trade (e.g., truck drivers supporting the movement of cargo between the United States and Mexico);
- Individuals engaged in official government travel or diplomatic travel;
  Members of the U.S. Armed Forces, and the spouses and children of members of the U.S. Armed Forces, returning to the United States; and
  Individuals engaged in military-related travel or operations.

So effectively speaking US citizens and permanent residents are not affected by these restrictions in any way. They may continue traveling freely in both directions unhindered.

---

Update Sept 18 - According to [Facebook post by the Mexico Consulate in San Diego](https://www.facebook.com/Consulmexsd/posts/10157853716753981), the border restrictions will be extended for another month until at least Oct 21.

> Mexico has proposed to the US the extension for an additional
> month of the restrictions on non-essential land travel on our common
> border, until Oct. 21, to avoid the spread of #COVID19. Restrictions
> applied since March will continue in operation & will not interrupt
> binational trade.

The DHS [Fact Sheet](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2020/08/14/fact-sheet-dhs-measures-border-limit-further-spread-coronavirus) has also been updated to include this extension.

---

Update Oct 19 - The border restrictions have been extended until at least November 21.  Statement [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHS_Wolf/status/1318191786783813634) by Chad Wolf:

> To continue to limit the spread of COVID, the US, Mexico, & Canada
> will extend the restrictions on non-essential travel through Nov 21.
> We are working closely with Mexico & Canada to identify safe criteria
> to ease the restrictions in the future & support our border
> communities.

The DHS [Fact Sheet](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2020/08/14/fact-sheet-dhs-measures-border-limit-further-spread-coronavirus) has again been updated.

---

Update Nov 20 - The border restrictions have been extended until at least December 21.  Statement [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHS_Wolf/status/1329523721682493459) by Chad Wolf:

> In order to continue to prevent the spread of COVID, the US, Mexico, &
> Canada will extend the restrictions on non-essential travel through
> Dec 21. We are working closely with Mexico & Canada to keep essential
> trade & travel open while also protecting our citizens from the virus.

---

Update Dec 11 - The border restrictions have been extended until at least January 21.  Statement Tweets by [Chad Wolf](https://twitter.com/DHS_Wolf/status/1337427031735345153) and by [Secretaría de Relaciones Exteriores de México](https://twitter.com/SRE_mx/status/1337419410210869248):

> In order to continue to prevent the spread of COVID, the US, Mexico, &
> Canada will extend the restrictions on non-essential travel through
> Jan. 21. We are working closely with Mexico & Canada to keep essential
> trade & travel open while also protecting our citizens from the virus.

> Las restricciones se mantendrán en los mismos términos en que se han
> desarrollado desde su implementación el 21 de marzo.
> Ambos países coordinarán las medidas sanitarias en la región
> fronteriza que estarán vigentes hasta las 23:59 hrs. del 21 de enero
> de 2021.

Translation:

> Restrictions will remain in the same terms as their implementation was
> developed on March 21.
> Both countries will coordinate health measures in the border region
> which will be in force until 23:59 hrs on 21 January 2021.

---

Update January 13 - The border restrictions have been extended until at least February 21.  Statement [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1349045993883447297) by Homeland Security:

> In order to continue to prevent the spread of #COVID, the US, Mexico,
> Canada will extend the restrictions on non-essential travel through
> Feb. 21. We are working closely with Mexico & Canada to keep essential
> trade & travel open while also protecting our citizens from the virus.

---

Update March - The border restrictions have been extended until at least March 21.  [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/SREMX/posts/4266311636715776) by Mexican government:

> Tras revisar el desarrollo de la propagación de #COVID19 y debido a
> que diversas entidades federativas se encuentran en  del Semáforo
> Epidemiológico,  planteó a  la extensión, por un mes más, de
> las restricciones al tránsito terrestre no esencial en su frontera
> común. Las restricciones se mantendrán en los mismos términos en que
> se han desarrollado desde su implementación el 21 de marzo de 2020.
> Ambos países coordinarán las medidas sanitarias en la región
> fronteriza que estarán vigentes hasta las 23:59 hrs. del 21 de marzo
> de 2021.

Translation by Facebook:

> After reviewing the development of the spread of #COVID19 and due to
> various federative entities in  of the Epidemiological Light, 
> raised  the extension, for one more month, of non-essential land
> transit restrictions in their common border. Restrictions will be
> maintained on the same terms as they have developed since their
> implementation on March 21, 2020. Both countries will coordinate
> sanitary measures in the border region that will be in effect until
> 23:59 hrs. of March 21, 2021.

---

Update 18th March - The border restrictions have been extended until at least 21st April.  Statement [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1372530432030433280) by Homeland Security:

> To prevent the further spread of COVID-19, and in coordination with
> our partners in Canada and Mexico, the United States is extending the
> restrictions on non-essential travel at our land borders through April
> 21, while ensuring continued flows of essential trade and travel.

And similar Tweets by Mexico - [Tweet 1](https://twitter.com/SRE_mx/status/1372572331990786048), [Tweet 2](https://twitter.com/SRE_mx/status/1372572333001543680)

> Para prevenir la propagación de #COVID19, Mexico impondrá a
> partir del 19 de marzo de 2021, restricciones al tránsito terrestre
> para actividades no esenciales en su frontera norte y sur.
> To prevent the spread of #COVID19, Mexico will
> impose as of March 19, 2021, restrictions on land traffic for
> non-essential activities on its northern and southern borders.

> Adicionalmente, el  @GobiernoMX  desplegará medidas de control
> sanitario en el norte y sur del país.
>
> Las restricciones al tránsito no esencial y las medidas sanitarias se
> mantendrán vigentes hasta las 23:59 hrs. del 21 de abril de 2021.
> Additionally, the  @GobiernoMX  It will
> deploy sanitary control measures in the north and south of the
> country.
>
> Restrictions on non-essential traffic and sanitary measures will
> remain in effect until 11:59 p.m. April 21, 2021.

---

Update April - The border restrictions have been extended until at least 21st May.  See [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1384513367826698242) by US DHS:

> To deter the spread of #COVID19 and protect our citizens, the United
> States is continuing restrictions on non-essential travel at our land
> borders through May 21, while maintaining the flow of essential trade
> and travel as we have for over a year.

and a follow up [tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1384513536123146241)

> We are guided by science and public health data and engaged in
> discussions with Canada and Mexico about easing restrictions as health
> conditions improve.

---

Update 20 May - The border restrictions have been extended until at least 21st June.  See [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1395379242280570881) by US DHS:

> To fight #COVID19 spread and protect our citizens, the U.S. is
> continuing restrictions on non-essential travel at land borders
> through June 21, while allowing essential trade & travel. We're
> working closely with Canada & Mexico to safely ease restrictions as
> conditions improve.

---

Update 20 June - The border restrictions have been extended until at least 21st July.  See [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1406724086370344963) by US DHS:

> To reduce the spread of #COVID19, the United States is extending
> restrictions on non-essential travel at our land and ferry crossings
> with Canada and Mexico through July 21, while ensuring access for
> essential trade & travel.

which was followed up by this [tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1406724087641219077):

> DHS also notes positive developments in recent weeks and is
> participating with other U.S. agencies in the White House’s expert
> working groups with Canada and Mexico to identify the conditions under
> which restrictions may be eased safely and sustainably.

---

Update 21 July - The border restrictions have been extended until at least 21st August.  See [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1417875283294699520) by US DHS:

> To decrease the spread of COVID-19, including the Delta variant, the
> United States is extending restrictions on non-essential travel at our
> land and ferry crossings with Canada and Mexico through August 21,
> while ensuring the continued flow of essential trade and travel.

and follow-up [tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1417875284469112837):

> DHS is in constant contact with Canadian and Mexican counterparts to
> identify the conditions under which restrictions may be eased safely
> and sustainably.

---

Update 20th August - Border restrictions for non-essential travel have been extended until at least 21st September.  [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1428689217232723973) by US DHS:

> To minimize the spread of #COVID19, including the Delta variant, the
> United States is extending restrictions on non-essential travel at our
> land and ferry crossings with Canada and Mexico through September 21,
> while continuing to ensure the flow of essential trade and travel.

---

Update 22nd September - The border restrictions for non-essential travel have been extended until 21st October.  [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1440486612731789326) by US DHS:

> To minimize the spread of #COVID19, including the Delta variant, the
> United States is extending restrictions on non-essential travel at our
> land and ferry crossings with Canada and Mexico through October 21,
> while continuing to ensure the flow of essential trade and travel.

which was followed by this [tweet](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1440486614497566724):

> This Notification may be amended or rescinded prior to that time,
> based on public health considerations.

---

Update October 2021:

From 8 November, 2021, fully vaccinated travelers may enter the US via the land borders for non-essential travel.

From January 2022, both essential and non-essential travelers must be fully vaccinated to enter the US via the land borders.

Source - there were a series of Tweets by the Department of Homeland Security on 20 October, 2021:

[Tweet 1](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800105259479042):

> As previously announced, starting Nov 8, travelers from Mexico and
> Canada who are fully vaccinated for #COVID19 may enter the U.S. for
> non-essential travel via land and ferry ports of entry.

[Tweet 2](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800106656174082):

> The timing of this change is aligned with the new international air
> travel system that will also be implemented in November.

[Tweet 3](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800107566374915):

> Restrictions continue to apply to non-essential travelers who are not
> fully vaccinated.

[Tweet 4](https://twitter.com/DHSgov/status/1450800108614868995):

> Beginning in January 2022, both essential and non-essential travelers
> from Canada and Mexico must be fully vaccinated for #COVID19 and
> provide related proof of vaccination to enter the U.S. via land or
> ferry ports of entry.

Comment: Looks like we're finally going to see a full unlocking of the borders, this time confirmed officially! WOOHOO!!! https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/10/25/a-proclamation-on-advancing-the-safe-resumption-of-global-travel-during-the-covid-19-pandemic/

Comment: @JonathanReez Well, not full unlocking yet - first step is fully vaccinated (which was expected), but there's a LOT of people currently traveling back and forth between US and Mexico that aren't vaccinated, and many that aren't traveling because again they're not vaccinated.  I'm not yet vaccinated - haven't been able to yet

Comment: Reopening day is finally here :)